# Aligning a Stack when using Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am using Shoes as a GUI toolkit for Ruby.

My question is how do u align a whole stack? I managed to align a para to the centre, but the :align does not work on a stack... Any ideas please

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a direct way but you can do something like that (it actually does horizontal and vertical centering):

```
Shoes.app do
 @s=stack :width=>300, :height=>100,  do 
  background red
 end
 @top=(@s.parent.height-@s.style[:height])/2
 @left=(@s.parent.width-@s.style[:width])/2
 @s.move(@left,@top)
end
```

You can probably wrap it in a function for easier usage.:

```
def center(elem)
  top=(elem.parent.height-elem.style[:height])/2
  left=(elem.parent.width-elem.style[:width])/2
  elem.move(left,top)
end
```

and then use it like that:

```
 ...
 @s=stack :width=>300, :height=>100,  do 
  background red
 end
 center(@s)
 ...
```

.. or you can extend the Stack class like that:

```
class Shoes::Types::Stack
 def center
  top=(self.parent.height-self.style[:height])/2
  left=(self.parent.width-self.style[:width])/2
  self.move(left,top)
 end
end
```

and than use it like that:

```
@s=stack :width=>300, :height=>100,  do 
  background red
end
@s.center
```

K